# yum error when installing memcached

Tags: centos, yum, memcached, rpm

trying to install memcached with "yum install memcached" and i'm getting all these errors which I have no idea how to solve.

```
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package memcached.x86_64 0:1.4.5-1.el5.rf set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: perl(AnyEvent) for package: memcached
--> Processing Dependency: perl(AnyEvent::Socket) for package: memcached
--> Processing Dependency: perl(AnyEvent::Handle) for package: memcached
--> Processing Dependency: perl(YAML) for package: memcached
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Term::ReadKey) for package: memcached
--> Processing Dependency: libevent-1.1a.so.1()(64bit) for package: memcached
--> Running transaction check
---> Package compat-libevent-11a.x86_64 0:3.2.1-1.el5.rf set to be updated
---> Package memcached.x86_64 0:1.4.5-1.el5.rf set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: perl(AnyEvent) for package: memcached
--> Processing Dependency: perl(AnyEvent::Socket) for package: memcached
--> Processing Dependency: perl(AnyEvent::Handle) for package: memcached
--> Processing Dependency: perl(YAML) for package: memcached
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Term::ReadKey) for package: memcached
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
memcached-1.4.5-1.el5.rf.x86_64 from rpmforge has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: perl(AnyEvent::Socket) is needed by package memcached-1.4.5-1.el5.rf.x86_64 (rpmforge)
memcached-1.4.5-1.el5.rf.x86_64 from rpmforge has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: perl(AnyEvent) is needed by package memcached-1.4.5-1.el5.rf.x86_64 (rpmforge)
memcached-1.4.5-1.el5.rf.x86_64 from rpmforge has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: perl(AnyEvent::Handle) is needed by package memcached-1.4.5-1.el5.rf.x86_64 (rpmforge)
memcached-1.4.5-1.el5.rf.x86_64 from rpmforge has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: perl(YAML) is needed by package memcached-1.4.5-1.el5.rf.x86_64 (rpmforge)
memcached-1.4.5-1.el5.rf.x86_64 from rpmforge has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: perl(Term::ReadKey) is needed by package memcached-1.4.5-1.el5.rf.x86_64 (rpmforge)

Packages skipped because of dependency problems:
    compat-libevent-11a-3.2.1-1.el5.rf.x86_64 from rpmforge
    memcached-1.4.5-1.el5.rf.x86_64 from rpmforge
```

The perl modules that its complaining about are already installed.

Any ideas?

Comment: Any particular reason you are installing this from RPMforge rather than EPEL?

Answer (score 2):

The Perl packages are excluded in the yum configuration due to cPanel. [Talk to them](http://www.cpanel.net/support.html) for a fix.